# Comparing smaller date range to a bigger one

Tags: laravel

I'm targeting a filter for an in-between date range. I do already have the basic filter

`->where('from', '>=', $from)->where('to', '<=', $to)`

example:

Date range to get: 01/01/2019 - 15/01/2019

Date range to use: 02/01/2019 - 03/01/2019

I should get the date range 01/01/2019 since it the range I use is in-between

Answer (score 1):

Flipped the condition and it somehow work:

```
->where('from', '<=', $from)
->where('to', '>=', $to)
```